What do the `indexToProgramIds` and `stackHeight` parts on transaction logs mean?
For example, below is the transaction logs for a basic sol transfer. What do the indexToProgramIds and stackHeight parts mean? It seems like stackHeight has to do with CPIs, but what is this data included? Didn't find any comments on what the indexToProgramIds is for.
"transaction": {
    "message": {
      "header": {
        "numReadonlySignedAccounts": 0,
        "numReadonlyUnsignedAccounts": 1,
        "numRequiredSignatures": 1
      },
      "accountKeys": [
        "3z9vL1zjN6qyAFHhHQdWYRTFAcy69pJydkZmSFBKHg1R",
        "5snoUseZG8s8CDFHrXY2ZHaCrJYsW457piktDmhyb5Jd",
        "11111111111111111111111111111111"
      ],
      "recentBlockhash": "DzfXchZJoLMG3cNftcf2sw7qatkkuwQf4xH15N5wkKAb",
      "instructions": [
        {
          "accounts": [
            0,
            1
          ],
          "data": "3Bxs4NN8M2Yn4TLb",
          "programIdIndex": 2,
          "stackHeight": null
        }
      ],
      "indexToProgramIds": {}
    },
    "signatures": [
      "5LrcE2f6uvydKRquEJ8xp19heGxSvqsVbcqUeFoiWbXe8JNip7ftPQNTAVPyTK7ijVdpkzmKKaAQR7MWMmujAhXD"
    ]
  }


indexToProgramIds: this object maps instruction indices within the transaction to the corresponding program IDs that executed those instructions.
stackHeight: this property indicates the depth of the call stack for the instruction. A higher stackHeight suggests the instruction involved nested calls or a Cross-Program Invocation (CPI) within the Solana runtime environment.
